# how can I make images show on a specific date on android device

Tags: android, image, date

Hi I'm wondering how to make an app show an image specific to the current date of the device. So if it's the 1st of January it will show the corresponding image for that date, and if it's the 5th of march it shows the image for the 5th of march.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class WidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static int currentImage = 0;

    int[] images = {R.drawable.j_1, R.drawable.j_2,R.drawable.j_3,R.drawable.j_4,
            R.drawable.j_5, R.drawable.j_6, R.drawable.j_7, R.drawable.j_8,
            R.drawable.j_9, R.drawable.j_10, R.drawable.j_11, R.drawable.j_12,
            R.drawable.j_13, R.drawable.j_14, R.drawable.j_15, R.drawable.j_16,
            R.drawable.j_17, R.drawable.j_18, R.drawable.j_19, R.drawable.j_20,
            R.drawable.j_21, R.drawable.j_22, R.drawable.j_23, R.drawable.j_24,
            R.drawable.j_25, R.drawable.j_26, R.drawable.j_27, R.drawable.j_28,
            R.drawable.j_29, R.drawable.j_30, R.drawable.j_31, 

            R.drawable.f_1, R.drawable.f_2, R.drawable.f_3, R.drawable.f_4, 
            R.drawable.f_5, R.drawable.f_6, R.drawable.f_7, R.drawable.f_8,
            R.drawable.f_9, R.drawable.f_10, R.drawable.f_11, R.drawable.f_12,
            R.drawable.f_13, R.drawable.f_14, R.drawable.f_15, R.drawable.f_16,
            R.drawable.f_17, R.drawable.f_18, R.drawable.f_19, R.drawable.f_20,
            R.drawable.f_21, R.drawable.f_22, R.drawable.f_23, R.drawable.f_24,
            R.drawable.f_25, R.drawable.f_26, R.drawable.f_27, R.drawable.f_28,};

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.appwidget.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE"));
        RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        remote.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image_view, getImageToSet());

    }



    private int getImageToSet(){
        currentImage++;
        return currentImage = currentImage % images.length ;
    }
}




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_text"
        android:src="@drawable/j_1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView"
        android:text="@string/button_view_text_up" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/downButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView"
        android:text="@string/button_view_text_down" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you want to read EXIF data of images, like Date taken?

Comment: Can you share some code to see what you have tried?

Comment: you want to show this image in your app or you want to make a popup window or widget ?

Comment: instead of using integer array to store the resource files, try using  HashMap to map the day with the correct resource...

Comment: Hi guys i just added the code hope it helps.The app is like a library of images that are relevant to different dates but when the app is opened it always shows the image for January 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor:

```
public WidgetIntentReceiver()
{
    currentImage = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can acheive it by two way

1.  [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_DATETIME2)

```
  String myAttribute=getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, exif);
  private String getTagString(String tag, ExifInterface exif)
   {
    return(tag + " : " + exif.getAttribute(tag) + "\n");
   }
```

2. [File Modified time](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)  if file.exists() and get time of modified file.